# Getting the first x characters from an array

Tags: python

Suppose I have an array like this `[4, 55, 578, 43, 81, 62, 7181]`

I'd like to retrieve the first 7 characters of this array disregarding cell. So in this case it would be `4555784` is this possible without concatenating the individual array elements? Thanks.

Comment: Want to clarify *without concatenating the individual array elements*?

Comment: `array[1]` is an individual array element pointing to `55`

Comment: The very act of returning the first 7 characters as a single string object *requires* concatenation at some point.

Comment: I meant combing the elements of the array into a single element then returning the first 7 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
''.join(map(str, arr))[:7]
```

If `arr` is very long this wastes time and space because it converts the whole thing to a string just to take the first 7 characters. Instead, you can only convert the first 7 elements (assuming each element has at least length one), convert *that* to a string, and then take the first 7 characters.

```
''.join(map(str, arr[:7]))[:7]
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to avoid concatenating the whole array. To avoid this you could do something like this:

```
a = [4, 55, 578, 43, 81, 62, 7181]

length = 7
chars = ''
counter = 0

while len(chars) < length:
    chars = chars + str(a[counter])
    counter = counter + 1

chars = chars[:length]
print chars, len(chars)
```

This keeps adding more characters from your array entries until the length of characters is larger than your chosen number. It then filters any extra chars added from the final entry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` and a list comprehension

```
"".join(str(x) for x in lst)[:7]
```